# What directories are included if the SafeDirectories flag is set on the DefaultDllImportSearchPaths attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dllimport, .net-4.8

The documentation for the [`DllImportSearchPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportsearchpath?view=netframework-4.7.2) enum states the following:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SafeDirectories | 4096 | Include the application directory, the %WinDir%\System32 directory, and user directories in the DLL search path. |

I am unclear on what "user directories in the DLL search path" means here. Specifically, the [standard DLL search order on windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) always includes "The directories listed under the PATH environment variable.", but in practice the DLL only seems to get loaded if it is placed directly next to the application executable.

I have searched and experimented quite a bit but I couldn't find any definite conclusion on this. Any hints?

Comment: Read the remainder of the table that you took that information from. Both the description and the numeric value for `SafeDirectories` indicate that it is a combination that includes `System32` and `UserDirectories`. The latter has its own description that would appear to answer your question.

Comment: DllImportSearchPath.UserDirectories is documented.  Not that it would help much, AddDllDirectory() is a very wonky winapi function.  Wonky enough to not worry about it too much.

Comment: Thanks both for the hints, I have figured everything out and will post a more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Some modern .NET libraries declare the [`DefaultDllImportSearchPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.defaultdllimportsearchpathsattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute with [`DllImportSearchPath.SafeDirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportsearchpath?view=netframework-4.7.2), which is itself a combination of the flags `DllImportSearchPath.System32` and `DllImportSearchPath.UserDirectories`.

The `DllImportSearchPath.UserDirectories` documentation clarifies that directories are added to the process wide DLL search path by calling `AddDllDirectory`.

Crucially, when this attribute is set, the directories under the default `PATH` environment variable are effectively ignored by `DllImport` for that assembly. Ironically, adding the same folders to the `PATH` environment variable may still be required, as this new process wide DLL search path does not supersede the native DLL search order used by some legacy libraries, and therefore some DLL dependencies may still fail to load if only `AddDllDirectory` is used.

Host applications on Windows requiring custom user directories for native libraries should therefore call [`AddDllDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory) for each native library folder they need to be scanned and probably also add them to the `PATH` environment variable anyway to cover all dynamic loading cases.

###### Historical note

These API calls are relatively recent. [Microsoft introduced them along with new API enhancements for securely loading external native libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-security-advisory-insecure-library-loading-could-allow-remote-code-execution-486ea436-2d47-27e5-6cb9-26ab7230c704) starting from Windows 8 and Windows 7 SP1 KB2533623.